# Spring Data Reactive Mongo Template: MongoDB cursor

Tags: spring, project-reactor, spring-mongodb, spring-mongo, spring-reactive

What is the recommended way to iterate over a large result with reactive mongo template?

I can't find a reactive alternative for the blocking MongoTemplate::stream() operation, which uses MongoDB cursor (and works perfectly well).

When I do the most obvious thing with Reactive template, my app works for a while, and then just stuck without any exceptions (Kotlin snippet below):

```
/* Repository */

fun findByStatus(status: Status): Flux<Event>

/* Service */

repository.findByStatus(status).buffer(1000).collect { events ->
       // process batch of events
}
```

I don't understand - if it tries to fetch all the results in memory, it should fail with OOM right away, but not stuck some time later, right?

What am I doing wrong?